# How do I write a question to play game again?

Tags: python, loops

I'm expanding upon the random number guessing game from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python and I can't figure out how to write the code for when the game asks if you want to play again.

More specifically, if the user types "yes" or "no" to wanting to play the game, the code does the appropriate thing. However, if the user types in anything else, I want it to say "Please answer yes or no" and then allow the user to enter another answer.

In this case, my code currently prints "Please answer yes or no", but then it treats the answer as "yes", so it starts the game again. I don't want it to immediately start a new game unless the user specifically types "yes". How can I do this?

Here's the code

```
import random

print ('Hello, what is your name?')
name = input ()

name = name.strip()

while True:

    print ('Well, ' + name + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')
    secretNumber = random.randint (1, 20)

    print ('DEBUG: Secret number is ' + str(secretNumber))

    print ('Take a guess.') 


    for guessesTaken in range (1, 7):
        try: 
            guess  = int (input ())
        
            if (guess < secretNumber and guessesTaken < 6):
                print ('Your guess is too low. Guess again.')
            elif (guess > secretNumber and guessesTaken < 6):
                print ('Your guess is too high. Guess again.')
            else:
                break # This condition is for the correct guess

        except ValueError:
            print ('You did not enter a number.') # This condition is for if a non-integer is entered.

    if (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken == 1):
        print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guess.')
         
    elif (guess == secretNumber and guessesTaken > 1): 
        print ('Good job, ' + name + '! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses.')
        
    else:
        print ('Sorry. Your guesses were all wrong. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))

    print ('Would you like to play again?') 

    answer = input ()
    answer = answer.lower()
    
    if answer == 'no': 
        print ('Ok.')
        break 
    elif answer == 'yes':
        print ('Ok, let\'s go!') 
    else: 
        print ('Please answer yes or no')
```

Comment: You need to wrap your entire "play again?" logic into it's own loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply have a second loop that will continue to prompt until a valid input is given.

```
usr_response = input('Would you like to play again: ').lower()
while usr_response not in ('yes','no'):
    usr_response = input('Invalid response. Please choose yes or no: ')
if usr_response == 'no':
    break
```

Comment: How do I format this? I tried replacing everything from "print ('Would you like to play again?') " in my code with yours and it continued the game even if the user inputs no

Comment: @nmatthews you still need to check the response. See my edit.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks! The user has to enter "no" or "yes" exactly with no space after, though. Do you know how I can make it so that "no " or "yes " would trigger the correct response?

Comment: @nmatthews you can remove leading/trailing whitespace with the function `.strip()`. So here it should be `usr_response.strip()`

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that the code checks for valid input only once. If the 2nd input is invalid as well, no condition is checked. For the solution, You should replace:

```
if answer == 'no': 
    print ('Ok.')
    break 
elif answer == 'yes':
    print ('Ok, let\'s go!') 
else: 
    print ('Please answer yes or no')
```

with:

```
list1 = ['yes', 'no']
while answer not in list1:
    print ('Please answer yes or no:')
    answer = input()
if answer == 'no': 
    print ('Ok.')
    break 
elif answer == 'yes':
    print ('Ok, let\'s go!')
```

Comment: It'll give the error `break outside loop`. Need to fix the indentation. I guess there's no need for `break` as well because the `while` loop is already checking condition.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish the code I wrote is just a snippet and the break is meant to be for the outer loop not the inner one